# css position absolute for child element of a table-cell div

Tags: html, css, css-tables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you relativlely or absolutely position items in a display:table-cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390046/can-you-relativlely-or-absolutely-position-items-in-a-displaytable-cell)

I have `display:table` layout. Demo is [here](http://jsbin.com/avozik/15/edit).

In second panel there is div `#pos` which is `position:absolute`. Similarly its parent element i.e. `div#two` is `position:relative`. When I have given `#pos { width:100% }` then it should get width of `div#two` right ? But it is getting width of `#wrapper` which is parent of `div#two`.

Is it so the behavior of table-cell arrangements? What do I have to do so that `div#pos` will have width of its parent. I do not want to hardcode width for `#pos`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually, `#pos { width: 100%; }` has the width of its parent, which is `#two`. It would also expand to that width, without setting the property explicitly, since it is a block element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set wrapper as a table right and `#one` and `#two` as `table-cell`, so #one and #two are now inline elements and your `div #pos which is position:absolute` is block. So now `#wrapper` which is the first block element in the heirarchy is the parent of #pos. Made a single-change.

```
#wrapper > div {
    display: table-row;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/avozik/17/edit#preview)** Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: no. I do not want data to be displayed in rows. Anyways, I understood what is the problem from your answer. So thanks.